# External ".xsd" file not included in release folder

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I am a WPF newbie. I have my first WPF project which is developed with C# and VS 2013. At the root of the project, there is an external XML schema file with "**.xsd**" extension that is used in my project codes. Inside VS 2013 environment, I code and run the project without seeing any issue.

Recently, I have built that project for Release. However, the built folder does **not** include that external ".xsd" file. As a result, on running that project outside VS 2013 environment, I get an exception that tells it could not find out that ".xsd" file.  Please tell me how I solve that issue. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file is set to be copied to output folder on compilation via the property window.

[image]